# Bitwise NOT with NaN: why does ToInt32 convert NaN to zero?

Tags: javascript

I normally use the double bitwise NOT (`~~`) as an alternative to `Math.floor`. Recently I found out that, when used with `NaN`, it will return `0`:

```js
console.log(~~NaN)
```

After some investigation I found out that, according to the [ECMAScript 2015 specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-bitwise-not-operator), the bitwise NOT uses `ToInt32` internaly...

> Let *oldValue* be ToInt32(GetValue(*expr*)).

... which, [by its turn](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toint32):

> If number is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return +0.

That explains the sequence in my snippet: `~~NaN --> ~~0 --> ~-1 --> 0`. However, to me, `0` seems to be an odd choice for `NaN`.

My question: why did the specification choose `0` as the returned value of `ToInt32(NaN)`? One could say *"because NaN is falsy"*, but that's not the case of +∞ or −∞. I'm preferably looking for some documented ECMA explanation (which therefore would not be *opinion based*).

Comment: Because bitwise operators only work with integers, and NaN is a float.

Comment: ECMA-262 tells you all you need to know: "*The abstract operation ToInt32 converts argument to one of 2^32 integer values…*", so it must produce an integer. Even where the argument isn't a number (and hence `ToNumber(argument)` produces NaN), it returns 0. This is the wrong place to ask why, better to try the TC39 mailing list or [ES Discuss](https://esdiscuss.org).

Comment: "However, to me, `0` seems to be an odd choice for `NaN`" What other value would be less odd?? -1? +1? -2\*\*31 or +2\*\*31-1? All seem rather arbitrary. There's no saner choice than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NaN is generally a floating-point concept, not an integer one. (Same with negative zero and the infinities. JavaScript numbers are IEEE floats.) ToInt32 produces only integers from −2**31 to 2**31−1, like you’d expect to see in a 32-bit integer type in most other languages.

Comment: "Negative zero and the infinities" would be a great band name.